# Angular 2 Call a service on app startup

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a provider and i want to run it on app initialization using APP_INITIALIZER , but somehow i keep getting an error

> Unhandled Promise rejection: appInits[i] is not a function ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: appInits[i] is not a function

Here is my provider :

```
@Injectable()
export class SendNotification {
  constructor(public http: Http) {
  Observable.interval(30 * 60 * 1000)
            .switchMap(res =>this.http.get(`http://localhost:8100/api/balance.pl?meternumber=0003080123&api=json`))
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(res => this.check(res))
}

private check(res) {
  console.log("Check wether to notify a user")
}
```

And on my app.module.ts , i called the provider as below :

```
providers: [{provide: APP_INITIALIZER,useClass: SendNotification,deps:[Http],multi: true}]
})
```

Any help will be appreciated ?

Comment: Is `appInits` a name from your code?

Comment: Nope , i don't have it in my codes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `useFactory` and call a method that returns a `Promise` or `Observable`

```
function notificationInitializer() : () => Promise<any> {
  return () => Promise.resolve(null);
}

providers: [
  SendNotification,
  { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: notificationInitializer, 
        deps:[Http, SendNotification],
        multi: true}]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , one quick question , where should notificationInitializer function go ?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Either in the same file or in a file you import to the current file so that the provider that references it is valid TS.

Comment: Works , thanks :-) can u use Observable instead of Promise tho ? which will be ideal approach as i want to use observable .

Comment: Sure, `Promise` and `Observable` are supported AFAIK.